# How to remove unity upper panel in my customizes ubuntu os

Tags: unity, customization, custom-distributions

Now these days I am working on a Ubuntu customization project. In which I want to remove unity upper bar panel and put this panel at the bottom of the screen.

I need manual method to change it. I am unable to install any third party application to do  it in Chroot Environment.

Help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer**: You cannot move the panel from the top to the bottom using the default Unity desktop.

**Detailed answer**: Unity Desktop(and Gnome Shell) is made to be simple and look the same on every computer. If you want something that is more customisable, you should try something else like KDE, XFCE, or the gnome2 which you can find in Ubuntu Sofwtare Center by seraching for gnome-fallback.